# uvm_event and system verilog event difference

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

What is the advantage of `uvm_event` over the SystemVerilog `event` ?
Can someone explain with small pseudo code ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UVM is nothing but a wrapper library developed over SystemVerilog. So, the `uvm_event` and SystemVerilog events are the same but `uvm_event` has some additional functionality.

From the [UVM Class reference](http://accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/uvm/UVM_1.1_Class_Reference_Final_06062011.pdf):

> The uvm_event class is a **wrapper class** around the SystemVerilog
>   event construct.  It provides some additional services such as setting
>   callbacks and maintaining the number of waiters.

A traditional Systemverilog event does not have functionality to **pass data** when event is triggered. While `uvm_event` adds this functionality. So, you can pass the transaction class handle when some event is triggered.

Just like traditional SV events, uvm_event also has **trigger and persistent trigger modes** (while SV has `wait(ev.triggered)` and `@(ev)` counterparts).

You can also **add callbacks** whenever an event is triggered. This is done by registering a callback class with particular event.

As far as events are concerned, they seem to be costly in terms of overhead. You can get many examples on `uvm_event` like [this one](http://bpdacha.blogspot.in/2014/06/how-to-insert-delays-in-tb-part-2.html).

Answer (score 4):

There are no *advantages* of using `uvm_event` over what is in the basic SystemVerilog `event` construct unless you need the extra functionality provided by the `uvm_event` The additional features include adding a uvm_object to be associated with the trigger, and booking information like keeping track of the number of waiters and the last time the uvm_event was triggered.

I have not seen much use for these additional features, and events in general are usually too low level for most testbenches to be dealing with.